# Is it possible that the the Big Bang is still taking Place?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

My question is the same  mechanism by which particles formed at the big bang still active here and now? To clarify the lambda CDM model fir instance say the observable universe was very dense at the beginning. So are such conditions still present in the current time somewhere in the universe and so are those mechanisms still active.

Comment: Welcome! Please ask just one question per post. Also, if you’d like to promote your blog, you’re welcome to do so in your user profile, but you shouldn’t do so in a question.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at your blog and skimmed your paper. I want to be sincere, and I am sorry if this sounds too harsh. You really need to better understand cosmogly and general relativity before you try to formulate your own theory. In particular, you **absolutely** need to go through the math.

As formulated here, your question isn't well posed and shows a number of misconceptions about the theories you are talking about. I read from your blog that you have a physics/engineering background, therefore I think you could be able to understand a book like Sean Carrol's Spacetime and Geometry. I'm not saying it will be easy, on the contrary, but it will really make you understand the subject.

Comment: @ray-light You will find freely downloadable notes by Sean Carroll [on his website](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/) as well as links to other notes.  There is a surprising amount of high quality material available freely (and legally).

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the feedback. I had started on Sean Caroll material sometime back and will continue. However I did want to share my idea and pout it out there. I will take a really long time for me go get a full understanding if the math as I have full time job. But nevertheless , I am committed to learning,